# How can I access Microsoft Sharepoint/OnDrive last children file content in java using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

Let say I have some folders in SharePoint.

Each folder contains Folder1->Folder2>Folder3....>File(txt.docx etc)
like this inside folder we have another folder and at the end some files of any type.

I want to access the files available in each folder with help of microsoft graph API in java sdk.

Below code will give me the root level files

```
JsonObject rootChildJson = graphClient.customRequest("/drives/"+driveId+
                          "/items/root/children") .buildRequest() .get();
```

and with the help of each item id of root folder I can get the next level file.

```
JsonObject innerChildren =graphClient.customRequest("/drives/"+driveId+
                                  "/items/"+itemId+"/children") .buildRequest() .get();
```

Is there an easy way to traverse the files available in each folder?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the path

```
drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-to-directory}:/children
```

Comment: Thanks!! Here what will be the {path-to-directory} value in my case?

Comment: folder1/folder2/folder3 etc

Comment: I am not sure about the path it should be dynamic one for just understanding purpose I have posted it in question. Path is not known in that case how we can access?

Comment: @varsha You can get the `path` from the parent path. For example, If you get the root files from `drives/{drive-id}/root/children`, the next level path should be `drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folder name}:/children`. You can loop the folders and list all the files.